# How to remove correct text input depending on while file is removed

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, upload

I have an application here: [APPLICATION](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/InputTest.php)

Please follow steps below:

1. Click on the `Add Question` button to append a file input into the table below:
2. By using the file input upload 2 images (one at a time), every time an image is successfully uploaded, it displays the name of the uploaded file underneath and below the table it displays it's id in a text input.
3. Now the problem is here, click on the `Remove` button for the second filename you uploaded, you will see it successfully removes the associated filename and remove button but it removes both text inputs underneath. This is incorrect, it should only remove the text input whose id is associated with the removed file name.

So that is my question, when the user clicks on the `Remove` button, how can I get only the text input associated with the removed file name to be removed rather than removing all the text inputs when a remove button is clicked?

Below is the code showing the file input and how it is appended into html table below, as well as showing the `.hiddenimg` div where it stores the text inputs:

**Jquery appending file input form:**

```
function GetFormImageCount(){ 
  return $('.imageuploadform').length + 1;
}

function insertQuestion(form) {



    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl_onthefly > tbody');
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
    var $image = $("<td width='17%' class='image'></td>");

    var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_image' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" +
        "<p class='imagef1_upload_form'><label>" +
        "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" +
        "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" +
        "<p class='imagef1_upload_process'>Loading...<br/><img src='Images/loader.gif' /></p>" +
        "<input type='hidden' class='numimage' name='numimage' value='" + GetFormImageCount() + "' />" +
        "</p><p class='imagemsg'></p><p class='listImage'></p>" +
        "<iframe class='upload_target_image' name='upload_target_image' src='/' style='width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");

    $image.append($fileImage);



    $tr.append($image);
    $tbody.append($tr);


}
```

**HTML Form and table where file input form is appended to and where the text inputs are stored in the `.hiddenimg` div tag:**

```
<form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post">


<table id="questionBtn" align="center">
<tr>
<th>
<input id="addQuestionBtn" name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" />
</th>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
<hr/>

<table id="qandatbl" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th width="17%" class="image">Image</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<div id="qandatbl_onthefly_container">
<table id="qandatbl_onthefly" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="hiddenimg"><!-- All uploaded image file ids go here --></div>

</form>
```

Below is code showing the hander for the file uploads, the function which starts the file upload and importantly the function which stops the file uploads where it controls the displaying of the filenames, text input and remove button and where it controls the removal when `Remove` button is clicked:

**Upload button Handler:**

```
  function imageClickHandler(imageuploadform){ 
  if(imageValidation(imageuploadform)){ 
      window.lastUploadImageIndex = $('.imageuploadform').index(imageuploadform); 
      return startImageUpload(imageuploadform); 
  } 
  return false;
```

**Start Upload:**

```
function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').show()
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').hide();
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagemsg').hide();
  sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

      return true;
}
```

**Upload finished:**

```
 var imagecounter = 0;

function stopImageUpload(success, imageID, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      imagecounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';   
            $('.hiddenimg').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<input type="text" name="imgid[]" id="'+imageID+'" value="' + imageID + '" />');
            $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" data-imageID="'+imageID+'"  data-image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>');
         }

      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_process').hide();
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagemsg').html(result);
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagemsg').show();
      $(sourceImageForm).find(".fileImage").replaceWith("<input type='file' class='fileImage' name='fileImage' />");
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').show();


  var _imagecounter = imagecounter;

$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {
    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + $(this).attr('data-image_file_name')).done(function(data) {
        $(".imagemsg" + _imagecounter).html(data);
    });

    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(".hiddenimg input").remove();
});

      return true;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i were to do it , then i will
add the image id as value of the button then retrieve it , and delete the associated input

```
$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename)
 + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" data-imageID="'+imageID+'"  data-image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '"  value="'+imageID+'">Remove</button>
<br/>
<hr/>
</div>')
```

then i will add that as the id of the text input or even in the name or class or what ever

```
$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {
    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + $(this).attr('data-image_file_name')).done(function(data) {
        $(".imagemsg" + _imagecounter).html(data);
    });
var buttonid = $(this).attr(value) // or class or what ever
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $("#"+ buttonid  +"").remove(); // this will be the id of the text input (you allready have that in your application .
});
```